# Where is setting option that allows to change the app's location?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Basically VS Code can't update because it is located in the different location to the default one. It tries to update itself in the default location, but fails. How can I change this without uninstalling it?
Here is a picture of the error: [image]

Here is what the log says: [image]

Comment: Is that what that log file says? How do you know this is the case?

Comment: Yes, this is what the log file says.